# Daily Log Rotation - retaining original

Tags: logging, syslog, logrotate

I'm working on Ubuntu 14.04 hosting a graylog server.
In the /var/log/upstart/ directory, I have a plaintext log of all the messages that come in - it's set to rotate every 3GB. However, the problem I was having before was that whenever it rotates, my "graylog-server.log" would be renamed "graylog-server.log.1" which I don't like. I added the "copy" keyword to the config, and now the file name is good! But it also leaves all the messages in the log file - which I want purged after they've been compressed.
So my question is...

- Is there a config keyword to help me accomplish this? I've looked at them but I'm new to logrotate so maybe there's something I've missed.
- Failing that, is there a way I can schedule the emptying of the logfile right after it's been rotated? I may drop a couple messages but that doesn't worry me too much.

Thanks!

Config:

```
/var/log/upstart/*server.* {
        size 3G
        missingok
        rotate 5
        compress
        notifempty
        nocreate
        copy
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually the latest rotated logfile (`file.1`) is kept uncompressed and is compressed in the next rotation (`file.1` -> `file.2.gz`).

If you want to compress the rotated log file immediatly you can add the

```
nodelaycompress
```

option.

From [`man logrotate`](https://linux.die.net/man/8/logrotate):

> **nodelaycompress**
>   Do not postpone compression of the previous log file to the next rotation cycle (this overrides the **delaycompress** option).

Comment: Awesome, this is what I needed.